# Adding to pandas dataframe line by line

Tags: python, pandas

I'm making a dataframe and I need to add to it line by line. I created the df with

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=('date', 'daily_high', 'daily_low'))
```

then I'm reading data from an API, so I run

```
for api in api_list:
    with urllib.request.urlopen(api) as url:
        data = json.loads(url.read().decode())
```

and I need to put different attributes from `data` in to the dataframe.

I tried to put

```
df = df.append({'date':datetime.fromtimestamp(data["currently"]["time"]).strftime("20%y%m%d"), 'daily_high' : data["daily"]["data"][0]["temperatureHigh"], 'daily_low': data["daily"]["data"][0]["temperatureLow"]},ignore_index=True)
```

in the for loop, but it was taking a long time and I'm not sure if this is good practice. Is there a better way to do this? Maybe I could create three separate series and join them together?

Comment: you just load the date as it is in new column, then use apply() function to create new columns from it.

Comment: What would the apply() function be referencing? I can load the date in but I'm not sure how I would get the daily_high and daily_low from just the date

Comment: Its taking more time may be because fetching data from url taking more time? Alternatively you can try saving data to a list and then creating dataframe from that. Ex: `df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['LIST_OF_DATES_FETCHED'], 'daily_high':[]})` and so on.

Comment: what does your `data` looks like after json loads, any 1 entry if you can show?

Comment: It would be much more efficient to store these fetches in a list rather than creating a dataframe for each pull and then appending to a larger df. It takes more overhead to create a dataframe object than a list object. After you've done all your fetches construct a dataframe from the list.

Comment: @d_kennetz That worked best! It took a minute to run but I think this is the best. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`pandas.DataFrame.append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) is inefficient for iterative approaches.

From documentation:

> Iteratively appending rows to a DataFrame can be more computationally
>   intensive than a single concatenate. A better solution is to append
>   those rows to a list and then concatenate the list with the original
>   DataFrame all at once.

As mentioned, concatenating results will be more efficient, but in your case using [`pandas.DataFrame.from_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) would be even more convenient.

Also, I would use [`requests`](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) library for requesting urls.

```
import requests

d = {}
d['date'] = []
d['daily_high'] = []
d['daily_low'] = []

for api_url in api_list:
    data = requests.get(api_url).json()
    d['date'].append(datetime.fromtimestamp(data["currently"]["time"]).strftime("20%y%m%d"))
    d['daily_high'].append(data["daily"]["data"][0]["temperatureHigh"])
    d['daily_low'].append(data["daily"]["data"][0]["temperatureLow"])
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
```